# How to include specific files in war using maven

Tags: java, maven, war, maven-war-plugin

I'm having some trouble trying to figure out a good way to control which resources to include in a war using maven. In my src/main/resources directory I have two files, logback.xml and logback-test.xml . What I want to be able to do is direct maven which of the two to include in the classpath based on the current maven profile. My initial thought was to define a property called log.config and then use that property in the configuration of maven-war-plugin. Something like:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <includes>                          
                            <include>${log.config}</include>                                    
                        </includes>                             
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

and a profile like

```
<profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <properties>
            <log.config>logback-test.xml</log.config>
        </properties>
</profile>
```

If I run the command

> mvn clean package -P test

I still end up with both versions of the logback file in the resulting war. I also tried using

```
<packagingIncludes>${log.config}</packagingIncludes>
```

with the same results.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better way to include/exclude files without having to copy/paste the maven-war-plugin definition into all my profiles?

Comment: You should NOT include any kind of logger configuration files in your source project as it is deployment specific.  Instead have a Maven project for each target (here development and deployment) and add the appropriate configuration file to each.  The less magic the better

Answer (score 1):

You can try pushing resources in the build though the profile (or exclude some):

```
<profiles>
      <profile>
         <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
         </activation>
         <id>Acceptance</id>
         <properties>
            <myDatabase.url>jdbc:informix-sqli://Adbhost:Aservice/Adatabase:INFORMIXSERVER=Aifxserver;IFX_LOCK_MODE_WAIT=1</myDatabase.url>
            <myDatabase.username>usernamea</myDatabase.username>
            <myDatabase.password>pass</myDatabase.password>
         </properties>
         <build>
            <resources>
               <resource>
                  <directory>resources</directory>
                  <includes>
                     <include>keypair_rsa_acceptance.p12</include>
                     <include>logback-test.xml</include>
                  </includes>
                  <excludes>
                     <exclude>logback.xml</exclude>
                  </excludes>
               </resource>
            </resources>
         </build>
      </profile>
      <profile>
         <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
         </activation>
         <id>Production</id>
         <properties>
            <myDatabase.url>jdbc:informix-sqli://Pdbhost:Pservice/Pdatabasep:INFORMIXSERVER=Pifxserver</myDatabase.url>
            <myDatabase.username>usernamep</myDatabase.username>
            <myDatabase.password>pass</myDatabase.password>
         </properties>
         <build>
            <resources>
               <resource>
                  <directory>resources</directory>
                  <includes>
                     <include>keypair_rsa_production.p12</include>
                     <include>logback.xml</include>
                  </includes>
                  <excludes>
                     <exclude>logback-test.xml</exclude>
                  </excludes>
               </resource>
            </resources>
         </build>
      </profile>
   </profiles>
```